# Get longest word from a list of words

Tags: objective-c

Is there a quick method that gets the largest word from an array of words?

`NSMutableArray wordlist`

Comment: Are you already aware that you can do it in a single loop traverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
NSString *longest = nil;
for(NSString *str in wordlist) {
    if (longest == nil || [str length] > [longest length]) {
        longest = str;
    } 
}
```

I'm not aware of any simpler method.

Comment: If you use an empty string as the initial value of longest then you can remove the longest == nil test.

Comment: Good point.  That said, thinking about it, even if longest == nil, [longest length] will evaluate to 0, and it'll still work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [this example](http://sokol8.blogspot.com/2011/04/sorting-nsarray-with-blocks.html) to sort an Array (but instead of the 'quality' sort in the example use a length sort on your strings) and then the longest string will be either at the top or at the end (depending on your sorting).

Comment: Sorting to find the max length element? You can do this in O(n). Then why sorting?

Comment: True, Tom's suggestion is much better. But instead of commenting on all of the answers, try to add one for yourself :-)

Comment: I was wondering whether the questioner is already aware of the loop traverse solution and looking for better one. Check there is a comment on the question. And I would write the same answer as of Tom without the nil check. But why should I spam with the answer that someone have already posted? Just one comment in Tom's answer is enough. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any objective C myself, but my solution would be to keep an integer 'longest' and a string 'longestWord' and initialise it to 0 and "". Then loop over the list and check if the current word is longer then the 'longest' value. If it is, store the new length and the current word. At the end of the loop, you have the longest word stored in the 'longestWord' variable.

Hope this helps